# DetourAttach breaks with Illegal Instruction 0xC000001D

Tags: c++, function-hooking, dll-injection, api-reversing

I am trying to detour a function using `DetourAttach()` in the following fashion:

```
hooks::logDebug("swresample-3Proxy.log", fmt::format("Try to attach hook. Function {:p}, hook {:p}.",
    *hook.first, hook.second));
writeProtectedMemory(hook.first, hook.second);
auto result = DetourAttach(hook.first, hook.second);
```

Where hook.first = `0x00007ff69f119ea0 {Gladius.exe!gladius::Game::main(int,char * *,char * *)} {0x8b4820ec83485340}    void * *`

hook.second = `0x00007ff818f51ef5 {swresample-3.dll!hooks::gamemainHooked(struct gladius::Game *,int,char * *,char * *)}    void *`

But the result comes with the following error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF69F119EA1 in Gladius.exe: 0xC000001D:
> Illegal Instruction.

And the question marks (see the screenshot) where the jump instruction supposed to be.

[image: Memory around detoured function]

Would appreciate some help in resolving this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with using [EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/) instead of Detours. I.e. replaced this piece of code:

```
writeProtectedMemory(hook.first, hook.second);
auto result = DetourAttach(hook.first, hook.second);
```

with this:

```
HOOK_TRACE_INFO hHook = { NULL }; // keep track of our hook
NTSTATUS result = LhInstallHook(
    hook.first,
    hook.second,
    NULL,
    &hHook);

ULONG ACLEntries[1] = { 0 };
LhSetInclusiveACL(ACLEntries, 1, &hHook);
```

Where hook.first = `0x00007ff69f119ea0 {Gladius.exe!gladius::Game::main(int,char * *,char * *)} {0x8b4820ec83485340}    void * *`

And hook.second = `0x00007ff818f51ef5 {swresample-3.dll!hooks::gamemainHooked(struct gladius::Game *,int,char * *,char * *)}    void *`

Now the app correctly jumps to the Hooked function.

P.S. Don't know what is the deal with DetoursAttach() for x64. I have compiled it specifically for that environment.

May be it doesn't know of how to pass the hook between the threads... Will check that option later.